# How to iterate through a string array equaled to a circle object?

Tags: java, css, javafx

This code is a connect 4 games and I'm trying to get it functional and take inputs for X and O, I, am using Circle objects for the first time not sure how to handle them I have the game launching but there is a problem with my array and the int data type, anytime I press a circle in my app randomly, I get errors.

this is my code main class:

```
package edu.citytech.gamesplus;

import java.net.URL;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GamesMainPlus extends Application {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(GamesMainPlus.class, args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.
             load(getClass().getResource("GamesPlus2.fxml"));

    stage.setTitle("Connect 4");
    Scene scene = new Scene(root); 
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();       


    URL url = getClass().getResource("GamesPlus2.css");
    if(url == null) {
        System.out.println("Resources not found Aborting");
        System.exit(-1);
    }



    String css = url .toExternalForm();
    scene.getStylesheets().add(css);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.show();


     }


  }
```

This is the Controller Class where the problem is:

```
package edu.citytech.gamesplus;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import edu.citytech.dao.WinningCombo;
import edu.citytech.dao.WinningComboDAO;
import edu.citytech.service.Connect4Service;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeLineCap;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeLineJoin;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType;

public class GamesPlusController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private GridPane fpGames2;

@FXML
private Label Title;

@FXML
private Label Name;

@FXML
private Label lbl_Message;

@FXML
private Button btn_Reset;

@FXML
void checkFloatOption(ActionEvent event) {

}


@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resource) {
    Ellipse ed = new Ellipse();

    int i = 0;
    for (int Rows = 0; Rows <= 5; Rows++)
        for (int Coulmn = 0; Coulmn <= 6; Coulmn++) {
            Circle circle = new Circle();

            circle.setCenterX(100.0f);
            circle.setCenterY(100.0f);
            circle.setRadius(45.0f);
            circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            circle.setStroke(Color.rgb(18, 97, 183));
            circle.setStrokeWidth(5);
            circle.setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);
            circle.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.ROUND);
            circle.setStrokeLineJoin(StrokeLineJoin.ROUND);
            circle.setStrokeMiterLimit(10);
            circle.setStrokeDashOffset(0);
            circles[i] = circle;

            circle.setUserData(i);// problems // come back figure out gravity
            circle.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> this.clickedEvent(e));
            fpGames2.add(circle, Coulmn, Rows);
            i++;

        }

}

private boolean isX = true;

private void clickedEvent(MouseEvent e) {
    Circle circle = (Circle) e.getSource();


    if (circle.getFill() != Color.WHITE) {
        lbl_Message.setText("This is not your turn!");
        return;
    }


    System.out.println(circle.getUserData());
    int cellNumber = Integer.parseInt( String.valueOf( circle.getUserData())); // problem


    String XorO = "";
    if (isX) {
        XorO = "X";
        circle.setUserData(XorO);
        circle.setFill(Color.RED);

    } else {
        XorO = "O";
        circle.setUserData(XorO);
        circle.setFill(Color.YELLOW);

    }
    isX = !isX;
    circle.setUserData(XorO);
    String[] moves = new String[42];//

    for (int i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        moves[i] = String.valueOf(circles[i].getUserData());
    }

    String newMove = (String) circle.getUserData(); //
    moves[cellNumber] = "?";
    circle.setUserData("?");


    int nextMove = Connect4Service.getValidCellMoves(moves, cellNumber);

    circles[nextMove].setUserData(newMove);
    circles[nextMove].getStyleClass().add(XorO);

    lbl_Message
            .setText("Current index " + cellNumber + " next valid move is " + nextMove + " Clicked on" + new Date());


}

private Circle[] circles = new Circle[42];

@FXML
void reset(ActionEvent event) {

    for (Circle circle : circles) {

        circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);

        circle.getStyleClass().removeIf(e -> e.equals("X") || e.equals("O"));
    }
    isX = true;
    lbl_Message.setText(" ");

    }

  }
```

This is my fxml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
 <?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
 <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
 <?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
 <?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
 <?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

 <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="1004.0" prefWidth="840.0" styleClass="gamecolor" stylesheets="@GamesPlus.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="edu.citytech.gamesplus.GamesPlusController">
 <children>
     <Label layoutX="242.0" layoutY="58.0" styleClass="title-label" text="Connect 4" textFill="#e8d102" />
  <Label fx:id="Name" layoutX="709.0" layoutY="974.0" text="Joshua Carpentier" textFill="#e8d102" />
  <Label fx:id="lbl_Message" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="966.0" prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="357.0" text="Label" textFill="#e8d102" />
  <Button fx:id="btn_Reset" layoutX="380.0" layoutY="875.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#reset" prefHeight="59.0" prefWidth="83.0" styleClass="gamecolor1" text="Reset" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#e8d102" />
  <GridPane fx:id="fpGames2" layoutX="73.0" layoutY="165.0" prefHeight="667.0" prefWidth="697.0">
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    </rowConstraints>
  </GridPane>
      </children>
 </AnchorPane>
```

my css file:

```
    .title-label{
       -fx-font-size: 70px;
       -fx-alignment: center;
     }


     .gamecolor{
       -fx-background-color: #1261B7;

    }

    .gamecolor1{
      -fx-background-color: #000000;
      -fx-border-color: #e8d102;

    }


     .custom-label {
       -fx-alignment: center;
       -fx-background-color: #bbb;
       -fx-border-color:black;
       -fx-min-height: 60px;
       -fx-min-width: 65px;
       -fx-border-insets: .55px

    }

    .border{
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-border-width: 5px 3px 5px 3px;
    -fx-border-style: solid;

    }


    .custom-label2, .winner {
     -fx-border-color:black;
     -fx-min-width: 100;
     -fx-min-height: 100;
     -fx-font-size: 60px;
     -fx-alignment: center;

   }

    .winner {   
      -fx-text-fill:red;
     }

    .possibleMove { 
     -fx-text-fill:blue;
     }
```

Comment: what gets printed out by System.out.println(circle.getUserData()); that precedes the line you have labeled //problem?

Comment: Also setUSerData wants some kind of object, but you are passing it the primitive type int. I'm wondering if instead you passed Integer.valueOf(i) things would improve

Comment: Descirbe the errors or provide the full stacktrace. Nobody wants to guess and often a stacktrace provides enough info to not require us to compile your code.

Comment: the System.out.println(circle.getUserData()); was for testing the output to make sure the array was working so when I press a circle it prints to the location of it on the array.

Comment: as for the errors when clicking on a spot on my connect 4 board, the numbers on to array generate but then an "X" or "O"   generates instead of a number for the position